# Can't download Google Drive videos using Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, video, download, google-chrome-devtools

i used to download videos from Google Drive by accessing Developer Tools, navigating to the Network tab, right-clicking on 'videoplayback', and selecting 'Open in new tab', after which I could download the video. However, now when I right-click on 'videoplayback' and choose 'Open in new tab', it immediately downloads a file instead of opening in a new tab. It worked once for a video I had previously downloaded when the icon next to 'Videoplayback' was green. However, when the icon is orange, it downloads as a file. I need to download these videos for my studying and I'm unsure how to proceed.

videos are read-only, so i can't just download them from GD or other service.

I attached a screens of how it works with other closed videos, and how it works for me now with the “problematic” one. Already tried to do this from other browser (edge, opera), same issue

Problematic:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7QGl.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOY8F.png)

Normal:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNj4n.png)
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RZzV.png)